# How do I deal with a row of enemies?

Tags: terra-battle

I've killed everything else on the map in 1 turn with 2 chain combos, but now there is a single row of enemies at the top that I have two free turns to deal with.  However, I don't know if there's any way of actually doing anything to them at this point.  What options do I have?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't attack this enemy formation.  You'll have to wait until the enemy moves in order to get a chance to attack.

If there is only one enemy in the corner then you can flank the enemy from both sides (horizontally and vertically) for an attack.  But as soon as there is another enemy besides the one in the corner you are out of luck.